# How can i style an angular2 component tag dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angular2-directives

New to angular2, so sorry if this is a stupid, easy question.

In angular1, i could create a simple directive like this, which will add a css class to the element, if a property of the model is true.

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', function () {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '<div>Hello</div>',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            myModel: '='
        },
        controller: function() {

        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (myModel.addClass)
                element.addClass('col-xs-2');
        }
    };

});
```

How can i do this in angular2?  Here is the component code for angular2, but i cannot find out how to add the class to the root element tag.

```
imports { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-directive',
    template: `
        <div>Hello</div>
    `,
})

export class MyDirectiveComponent {
    @Input()
    myModel: Object;
}
```

Comment: You can also use the Angular 2 property syntax to add CSS classes to elements. '`<div [className]="'blue'">`

Comment: What do you mean by "root element tag"? The root component, the one that is bootstrapped doesn't support to set attributes, classes, styles, ... on itself using Angular bindings.

Comment: Yes, i mean the root tag, so in the example it would be the tag my-directive.

Comment: `my-directive` doesn't indicate it's the root tag. `my-app` is commonly used in the examples as root component. There is no root directive because the root has to be a component.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ngClass binding...

```
<div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-2': myModel.addClass}">
```

Comment: say myModel.addClass has a value of either 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, how would i add col-xs-X where X is the value in addClass??

Comment: <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-'+myModel.addClass: myModel.addClass}">

Answer (score 0):

Easy way (but not recommended ) would be

```
<div [style]="myStyle"></div>
```

and in your component

```
export class MyDirectiveComponent {
    @Input()
    myModel: Object;

   changeModel(col : number){
    this.myModel = 'col-xs-'+col; // Gives you col-xs-1 or 2 ....based on input
   }
}
```